# I need to open a new activity from grid view. Android studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview

I have created a grid layout.
But when I try to open different activities from different element of grid,
it is not working.
............
All the grid elements are opening same activity.

This is my mainactivity code

```
package com.learning.careerclub;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import com.learning.careerclub.quiz_grammar.grammar_quiz;


public class grammar_quiz_category extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grammar_quiz_category);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);


        //Set Event
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
        //setToggleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setToggleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            final CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
                        Toast.makeText(grammar_quiz_category.this, "State : True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //Change background color
                        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        Toast.makeText(grammar_quiz_category.this, "State : False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(grammar_quiz_category.this, grammar_quiz.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info", "This is activity from card item index  " + finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), mainpage.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

}
```

This is my layout code
No other classes are involved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".grammar_quiz_category">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:text="Aptitude categories"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="14dp"
        >

        <!-- Row 1 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/me_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Me"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/family_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Family"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/lovely_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Lovely"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/team_time"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Team"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->

        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/friends"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Friends"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="Calendars"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the only acivity used
no adapter classes available or used here
++++++++++
Help me to open different activities
+++++++++++
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us go through your code a bit. Here is the first part which you are calling

```java
setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
```

This function call takes place and we go through the following

```java
private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        //Loop all child item of Main Grid
        for (int i = 0; i < mainGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
            //You can see , all child item is CardView , so we just cast object to CardView
            CardView cardView = (CardView) mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(grammar_quiz_category.this, grammar_quiz.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info", "This is activity from card item index  " + finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

What is happening here is you are looping through all the children of your layout and setting `onClickListener()` to them.

Inside the `onClickListener()` this takes place

```java
 Intent intent = new Intent(grammar_quiz_category.this, grammar_quiz.class);
                    intent.putExtra("info", "This is activity from card item index  " + finalI);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

As you can see since you are setting the same activity to open up on all children of your `GridLayout`, so clicking on them the same action takes place.

Coming to the solution what you need might be is some way or some mapping to assign to your GridLayout children or even just compare by their XML IDs to know what activity to open while setting `onClickListener`

Comment: sorry I'm not getting you can you please say it clearly since I'm new to android studio.

Comment: You are setting the same click action on all your views that is why they are all starting the same activity when clicked.

Comment: oh ok. So how can I change that ?

Comment: Implement your own logic on how to supply them either with what all click actions you want to perform @FrancisRaj or implement a separate click listener for each one of them.

Comment: It is throwing errors. If u don't mind can u send a sample code for that?